# Count number of rows in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

I have a cassandra table **subscription** with following columns:

```
firmId, //partition key
acct_info,
appId,
can
```

firmId is the partition key. There is no clustering key.

The field **appId** can have one of the three values:

```
appId1, appId2, appId3
```

I want the count of number of rows for each appId values. Example: number of rows with appId1, number of rows with appId2 and number of rows with appId3.

I tried

```
select COUNT(*) from subscription;
select COUNT(appId) from subscription;
```

which gives me the total row count of the table. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using CQL query.

You are looking for something like `SELECT appId,COUNT(appId) FROM subscription GROUP BY appId` which is **NOT Posible** in cassandra.

Try using spark-cassandra-connector to get the count of existing records and create a separate table using `counters` where you can maintain count (update values during insert and delete)

Comment: What about ALLOW FILTERING?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't query like this with your current data model.**

> In Cassandra, data are modeled based on your query

So you should model your data in such way, that you can query like this.

For Example create a new table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE appIdCounter(
    appId text PRIMARY KEY,
    count counter
);
```

So whenever a new appId value appeared increment the value of count by one.

```
UPDATE appIdCounter SET count = count + 1 WHERE appId = ?;
```

Now you can easily get the count of each appID, with just a select query

```
SELECT * FROM appIdCounter ;
```

Comment: Your answer makes it seem like it's impossible when in fact it's possible to get the required count in OP's table itself using ALLOW FILTERING. How that method compares to your method is a separate matter.

Comment: @VishalSharma Maybe it's possible in Cassandra 3.11 or above using ALLOW FILTERING. But **CAUTION: Only use ALLOW FILTERING for development! **

Answer (score 0):

As all the others stated: this is not possible in this simple way, maybe you are better of using a SQL database.

Ashraful's answer regarding counters works very good, unless you have a TTL on the data, since the counter would not automatically decrement in such a case.

There is also another way, which might or might not help you, but this would require the appId to be a clustering key, which changes the semantics of your data model. If it was: You could create a materialized view basically transposing your data model and make the appId the primary and the firmId the secondary key. This on the other hand has some different backdraws: writes to the view are considerable slower, so if you have a write heavy workload, don't use a view. Also, since your your appId, the row key in the view, can only take 3 values, you will not get a good distribution in your cluster as you produce only 3 rows basically.

Disclaimer: I never used materialized views in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the respective counts using the following CQL statements:

```
select count(*) from subscription WHERE appid = 'appId1' ALLOW FILTERING ;
select count(*) from subscription WHERE appid = 'appId2' ALLOW FILTERING ;
select count(*) from subscription WHERE appid = 'appId3' ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

I tested this in Cassandra 3.11.2. I don't know why everyone else is saying it's not possible.

Comment: What you are suggesting is bad design and should be avoided... appId is not partition key... nor it is part of clustering key... Though you will argue that secondary index can be created and queried... what you tested is on limited set of data... try inserting more data and your query will start timing out.

Comment: I didn't mean that this is a good design but none of the answers mentioned this so I had to include this. And timeout threshold can also be increased. Although I couldn't increase it beyond 30 seconds (I don't know the reason behind this). That amount of time is enough to run this query on atleast a million rows. Again, it might not be the best way, but it will get the job done in several cases.